# Guava: Iterables.filter VS Collections2.filter, any big difference?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, guava

I'd like to know in Guava if there are any differences between the [`Iterables.filter(Iterable, Predicate)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Predicate-) and [`Collections2.filter(Collection, Predicate)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter-java.util.Collection-com.google.common.base.Predicate-) methods?

They seem to both maintain the iteration order, and to provide a live view.
Javadoc says calling `Collections2.filter().size()` will iterate over all elements.

Suppose I have a predicate to filter a list of items, and as a result I want the number of items left in the view (or the list, doesn't matter). What am I supposed to use?
It seems simpler to use `Collections2.filter` as the `size()` method is provided by `Collection`s.

But in the background, is there a difference between:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(
    Iterables.filter(lead.getActions(), isRealActionDoneByUserPredicate)
).size();
```

And:

```
Collections2.filter(lead.getActions(),isRealActionDoneByUserPredicate).size();
```

---

By the way, is building an `ImmutableList` faster than building a normal `ArrayList`?

Comment: Just stating the obviously obvious: one gives you `Iterable` and the other gives you `Collection`. Underneath `Collections2.filter` uses `FilteredCollection` [link](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.java#133) that delegates many things to `Iterables`/`Iterators` so there should be no functional differences. For example `FilteredCollection#size()` is exactly `Iterators.size(Iterators.filter(unfiltered.iterator(), predicate))` as @Louis Wasserman's answer indicates.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

```
Collections2.filter(elements, predicate).size()
```

is preferable, as it does no copying -- both `filter` methods return a *view* -- but

```
Iterables.size(Iterables.filter(elements, predicate))
```

is essentially equivalent, and will similarly find the answer without any copying.

As for the relative speed of constructing an `ArrayList` versus an `ImmutableList`, it varies by which construction method you use:

- `ImmutableList.copyOf(collection)` should take almost exactly the same amount of time.  (It has to check for nulls, but that's cheap.)
- `ImmutableList.builder()....build()` takes a small constant factor longer, because it has to use an `ArrayList` inside the `Builder`, since we don't know in advance how many elements will be added.
- `ImmutableList.of(...)` will have about equal speed.

That said, the *conceptual* benefits of using `ImmutableList` often outweigh the small performance costs, especially if you'll be passing the lists around frequently.

Comment: Thanks. i think you mean Iterables.size() i don't find any Iterables.length()

Comment: Tangential but have you guys considered giving `Builder`s a constructor that takes `int expectedSize` (and exposing corresponding `builder(int)` methods? Or would there be too little benefit for the added noise in the API?

Comment: Nevermind, found [your debate about that](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=196).

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why the change from "Guava team member" to "Guava contributor"?

Comment: Meh, whatever I feel like that day.  (I'm starting at Google on the team proper in the fall, but I've been contributing for almost two years now.)

Comment: What is difference between `Iterables.transform` and `Collections2.transform` ?